# vb6 Read Write Binary File

Tags: vb6

I am trying to make a project that can allows me to read from a specific file as binary and from an specific offset in the file.

I found the following code without the main souce:

```
Sub GetData()
Dim nFileNum As Integer, sLocation1 As String, sLocation2 As String 'declarations
nFileNum = FreeFile 'get file ID
Open App.Path & "\Hologram.bin" For Binary Access Read Lock Read Write As #nFileNum 'file to open
sLocation1 = Space$(10) 'my first offset is 10 chars long, set a string placeholder must equal the size of data you want to hold
sLocation2 = Space$(32) 'my second offset is 32 chars longs, set a string placeholder must equal the size of data you want to hold
Get #nFileNum, 12000, sLocation1 'The offset location in Binary of the data I want to show (+1 to offset because we start at 0!)
Text1.Text = sLocation1  'display the 10 chars data in a textbox
Get #nFileNum, 12500, sLoation2 ' The offset location in Binary of the data I want to show (+1 to offset because we start at 0!)
Text2.Text = sLocation2  'display the 32 chars data in a textbox
Close #nFileNum  'Cloase the file
End Sub  'Call GetData()

Sub WriteBin()
Dim sFileText As String 'declarations
Dim iFileNo As Integer
iFileNo = FreeFile
Dim nFileNum As Integer
nFileNum = FreeFile 'get random file number
Open App.Path & "filename.bin" For Binary Access Write Lock Read Write As #nFileNum 'open file for edit
Put #nFileNum, 12000, Text1.Text 'Offset is +1 because we start at 0! write data from textbox1 to offset location
Put #nFileNum, 12500, Text2.Text 'Offset is +1 because we start at 0! write data from textbox2 to offset location
Close #nFileNum 'Call WriteBin()
End Sub
```

I would like to find the rest of this code so I can use it.
Thanks

Comment: `GetData` shows the mechanics of doing what you need.  It opens a binary file, reads data from 2 specific locations, displays that data and closes the file.  `GetData` would be called from some other place in your code.  What specifically are you looking for?

Comment: Hello there, the code above loads a file as binary and displays in a textbox field a given offset from the loaded file. the idea is to be able to read that offset and then be able to change it. but I am getting a syntax error, some sort of overflow error. if I give an offset of 10, that works, but if I set an offset of 6D9711, then I get errors. thanks

Comment: A overflow isn't a syntax error, but a runtime error. Show us the exact error message, the line of code it points towards and what values you used for the variables involved in that line of code. Here's long shot: you mention hexadecimals. Have you properly prefixed them with `&H`, e.g. `&H6D9711` so that VB can interpret them as a hexadecimal number?

Comment: Hello Hel, thank you for pointing me the &H, I was correcting the issue by converting it to blocks, but it is much easier to ad &H as you suggested. now the only problem I have is that not all files have the same Offset. for example, from 10 .bin files, some have the same exact Offset but others do not. The .bin files am dealing with have text on them. so the idea is to load them one by one on my project so I can change their display text. These .bin files have text that shows in my hologram display, and I found this to be the easiest way to edit them.

Comment: I was wondering if I could add a way to search for an specify name in the file as a hex. for example: 4E 61 6D 65.