# Read bytes from binary file and write that value into another binary file in VB6

Tags: vb6

I have one binary file and want to read value from a specific location of that file.
and once I have the value, I want to write that value in the another file on same location

For instance, I have two binary files **A1 and B1**
Now I want to read a value from file **A1** which stores in binary location **0000 003E - 0000 0041**.

Once I have the value, will have to write value on the same location of file **B1**

It's **VB6** not VBA and I don't understand how to read and write bytes from specific byte location in VB6

Will appreciate if I get the proper solution in **VB6 code**.

Comment: Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64807224/5162073) that might be helpful.

Comment: Press F1, look up `Open ... For Binary`, `Get #`, `Put #`, `Seek #`. The first three are demonstrated in the example @BrianMStafford linked above.

Answer (score 0):

Add this [**mdStreamSupport.bas**](https://gist.github.com/wqweto/f2c5c99a7c1646ceec17b252eb786506) module to a new Std-EXE project and change source and destination file names as used with `CopyChunk` function in the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim sError          As String
    
    If Not CopyChunk("D:\TEMP\aaa.src", "D:\TEMP\aaa.dest", _
                Position:=&H3E, _
                Size:=&H41 - &H3E + 1, _
                Error:=sError) Then
        MsgBox "Error copying chunk" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & sError, vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub

Private Function CopyChunk( _
            SourceFile As String, _
            DestFile As String, _
            ByVal Position As Currency, _
            ByVal Size As Long, _
            Optional Error As String) As Boolean
    Dim pSrc            As stdole.IUnknown
    Dim pDest           As stdole.IUnknown
    Dim baData()        As Byte
    
    On Error GoTo EH
    Set pSrc = StreamOpenFile(SourceFile)
    If pSrc Is Nothing Then
        Error = "Cannot open source file (" & SourceFile & ")"
        GoTo QH
    End If
    Set pDest = StreamOpenFile(DestFile, AlwaysCreate:=False)
    If pDest Is Nothing Then
        Error = "Cannot open destination file (" & DestFile & ")"
        GoTo QH
    End If
    If StreamSeekAbsolute(pSrc, Position) <> Position Then
        Error = "Cannot position source file to " & Position
        GoTo QH
    End If
    If StreamSeekAbsolute(pDest, Position) <> Position Then
        Error = "Cannot position destination file to " & Position
        GoTo QH
    End If
    baData = StreamReadBytes(pSrc, Size)
    If UBound(baData) + 1 <> Size Then
        Error = "Cannot read chunk from source file (" & Size & ")"
        GoTo QH
    End If
    If StreamWriteBytes(pDest, baData) <> Size Then
        Error = "Cannot write chunk to destination file (" & Size & ")"
        GoTo QH
    End If
    '--- success
    CopyChunk = True
QH:
    Exit Function
EH:
    Error = Err.Description
End Function
```